# Touchpad not working after Windows 10 1803 update

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, asus-laptop, windows-10-v1803

I am using an Asus ROG G502VY with Windows 10 Family version 1803.

After updating to Windows 10 version 1803 from a previous version of Windows 10, and after rebooting my computer, the touchpad randomly stops working, in 5 minutes or 1 hour, it depends. I can use my mouse without any issue.

The touchpad doesn't appear in the Device Manager even when it's working. I tried to uninstall and re-install ATKPackage and Asus Smart Gestures but nothing changed.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried the Asus download center for the driver? https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/ BTW, you'll need to specify 502VM, VS or VT and OS.

Comment: Yes I tried.. there is nothing which fixed the issue. I have a 502VY with Windows 10 Family

Comment: Odd, I can't seem to find 502VY model on the driver download site of the vendor. I searched ROG and others so not sure if I'm overlooking it or what. I would see if there is a BIOS firmware upgrade available though and update it. Then uninstall the drivers from the machine or device manager, reboot the machine and test it out and see if it works without installing and it so leave as it and see if it act better. Otherwise after the reboot reinstall the latest touchpad drivers once BIOS firmware is updated and then see how it goes. I'd give direct links if I could find the model 502VY.

Comment: Try just to disable and re-enable the touchpad in Device Manager. There are reports that this manipulation is required after boot to avoid such problems.

Comment: I know my computer doesn't appear on the Asus website, I don't know why... Should I give a try to this link : http://www.driversfree.org/fr/catalogue-de-pilotes/pilotes-pour-ordinateurs-portables/asus/asus-g502vy ?

Comment: Yes but the touchpad doesn't appear in the device manager, even when it's working.

Comment: The touchpad may appear under "I2C HID Device" and its name could be something similar to `ELAN1203`.

Comment: I have an I2C HID Device called HID Mouse. It tells me that the driver date is 21/06/2006 and the version 10.0.17134.1, signed by Microsoft Windows. After booting, when my touchpad was still working, I tried to desactivate it but the touchpad was still working after that so I don't know... Its access path is HID\ELAN1200&COL01\5&150F7C31&0&0000, there is ELAN1200 in it so I think it's the touchpad

Comment: This is the touchpad. Try: (1) Disable and re-enable. (2) ASUS support says to install the ATK driver first and then the touchpad driver. (3) Go to Control panel -> Programs and Features -> ASUS Smart Gesture -> Repair. (4) Install [Elantech Touchpad 11.5.22.2](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Commercial_NB/DriversForWin10/Touchpad/TouchPad_ELAN_Win10_64_VER115222.zip) or maybe [this one](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/downloads/DS112631) (if they install, if they don't work go back to your current version). (5) Uninstall the device and reboot (ensure first you can reinstall current driver).

Comment: Okay I tried every single solution but none of them worked...

Comment: Unfortunately, the only other solution I can think of, until Microsoft fixes the problem (if ever), is to use an external mouse.

Comment: I think I will try a complete Windows reinstallation.. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You sure it is not `ROG GL502VY`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Asus ROG GL502VT. After looking around everywhere, the best solution I could come up with **for the time being** was to roll back the OS to before the update.

Click on the start/windows button, then click on the gear icon (settings). Click on "Update and Security", and if you scroll down a little, there's an option to undo the 1803 update. It won't harm your files, but will change programs you installed since the update. Since neither Asus or Microsoft could give me a solution, I did this. But it is, in the end, a temporary solution.

Now, the downside is that rolling back the update will cause bugs that were in the old version to come back. So, after undoing the 1803 update, my problem is that I can't access "Update and Security" under Settings any more. This seemed to be an issue in the old version. Ultimately, it comes down to whether this cost is worth the benefit of getting your touchpad working again. For me, it was worth it, as there are other ways to command your computer to do update-related things without accessing that option from Settings.

Let me know if this works. In the meantime, we need to hound them for a permanent fix.

EDIT: 
The following is probably what Asus Support will tell you:

"Please follow the steps below to perform a system restore on your unit:

Step 1: Please press the Windows key and R for the Run utility.
Please type the command rstrui.exe and then press enter to initiate System Restore.

Step 2: The System Restore wizard should appear.

Step 3: Please select next for a list of dates and times to restore the unit to.
If there is an option that allows you to see more restore points, please select this option please.

Step 4: Please select the appropriate date and select Next to start the process.

Step 5: Please select Finish to confirm doing restoring the process to the date selected.

We do value your business, thank you for being a part of the ASUS family.

If you have any further questions, comments, or concerns please do not hesitate to let us know, we will be more than happy to assist you. "

That didn't work for me. Roll back the update like I described above and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it happened directly after updating, it is a software bug which has been imposed by Microsoft or the manufacturer.

You could try installing legacy touchscreen drivers, but I doubt it would work.
Better try rolling back and wait for a later update. I know, some bugs solved by the update would come back, but it is not worse than what you lived with before the update, and **you can re-do the update at any time.**

Comment: Isn't the driver pre-installed?